# Cant Download Deluge due to Application Indicator and Panel Indicator Applet

Tags: indicator, panel, applet, deluge

[image]

Cannot download Deluge due to the following problem, Ubuntu Software Center indicates these items must be removed:

1. Application Indicator
2. Panel Indicator applet

Comment: What version of **Ubuntu**, and 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: Hey david6 so sorry I havent responded to your help, I have been away from Linux for a minute. But I am back. I will have found out that I am using version 4.10 as best I can tell. Still dont know how to tell if I downloaded 32 or 64 bit. But since I am using a Chromebook2 i would imagine it is 32 bit since I have heard it is a light operating system.